# Map Reduce with multiprocessing

Tags: python, mapreduce

```
import multiprocessing

data = range(10)

def map_func(i):
    return [i]

def reduce_func(a,b):
    return a+b

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
p.map(map_func, data)
```

How can I use `reduce_func()` as a reduce function for the paralelised `map_func()`.

Here is a `pySpark` example of what I want to do:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
result = rdd.map(map_func)
final_result = result.reduce(reduce_func)
```

Comment: `functools.reduce(reduce_func, p.map(map_func, data))` produces a list of numbers 0 to 9, the randomness depends on the order multiprocessing is mapping the data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` blocks until the result is ready. Randomness is not possible. To achieve a random processing order, use the `imap_unordered()` method:

```
from functools import reduce

result = p.imap_unordered(map_func, data)
final_result = reduce(reduce_func, result)

# Three different runs:
# [0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3]
# [0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9]
# [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the reduce with multiprocessing?